# Unable to install Skype ("Unmet dependencies" error)

Tags: package-management, software-installation, skype

Trying to install skype on Ubuntu 12, I faced and issue. When I type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

I get an error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
skype is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: lib32stdc++6 (>= 4.1.1-21) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: lib32asound2 (> 1.0.14) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: ia32-libs but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1-21+ia32.libs.1.19) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How do I solve it? Is the way I'm using the right one to install skype?

UPDATE: If I try to do

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32asound2 ia32-libs libc6-i386 lib32gcc1 skype
```

then I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
skype is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
 lib32asound2 : Depends: libasound2 (= 1.0.25-1ubuntu10)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: i think u already install skype, bqz it says `skype is already the newest version.`, look at application menu

Comment: I have the same issue here with 12.10 x64, I get the same error, looks like its a packaging issue as Skype installs fine on 12.10 x32.

Comment: When it says use "apt-get -f install" do not append skype in the end e.g "apt-get -f install skype" won't work. This applicable to other applications as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your dependencies are broken even though skype is installed.
run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This should help to fix the broken dependancies

Answer (score 1):

Use only `sudo apt-get install -f` to install.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe type:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32asound2 ia32-libs libc6-i386 lib32gcc1 skype
```

**EDIT** Try typing:

```
sudo apt-get install -f skype
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help me.

Comment: what output it gived? @AlexMaslakov

Comment: Look at my update

Comment: @AlexMaslakov ok, saw, look at updated answer

Comment: The result is equal to the first error.

Comment: can u go to chat room to talk about this....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4288/discussion-between--and-alex-maslakov) @AlexMaslakov

Answer (score 0):

according to the errors listed , **Skype is already installed** , the above are dependency errors .

You need to install **ia32-libs-multiarch** by

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
```

then try your method method

Comment: ya, but the problem is with 32 bit libs, it can't be installed, come to chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4288/discussion-between--and-alex-maslakov

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick :)

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

Found on: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-skype-in-ubuntu-12-04precise.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm New. Try install [UBUNTU TWEAK](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/).

[image]

Hope it help.